# Chern classes of minimal 3-folds of general type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a minimal $3$-fold of general type, 
by a famous result of Miyaoka we know that 
the class $3c_2(X)-c_1(X)^2$ is a pseudo-effective $1$-cycle.

Is it known if the class $35c_1(X)^2 - c_2(X)$ is a pseudo-effective $1$-cycle?

Or in general, do we know if $ac_1(X)^2-c_2(X)$ will be a pseudo-effective $1$-cycle
for some fixed $a$?

Clearly, this question is motivated by the corresponding inequality between Chern classes of surfaces of general type.